# Prove that $f \times g$ is injective

Tags: functions

> Consider the maps $f:U_1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $g:U_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where
>
> $f(x^1,x^2)=x^2$ and $g(y^1,y^2)=y^2$
>
> $U_1=\{(x^1,x^2) \ | \ x^1>0\}$ and $U_2=\{(y^1,y^2) \ | \ y^1<0 \}$
>
> Where $x^i$ is the $i$-th coordinate
>
> Prove that $f \times g$ is injective

Suppose that $(f \times g) \big( (x^1,x^2),(y^1,y^2)\big) =(f \times g) \big( (a^1,a^2),(b^1,b^2)\big)$.

Then $(x^2,y^2)=(a^2,b^2)$ which implies that $x^2=a^2$ and $y^2=b^2$.

Now, we have to show that $x^1=a^1$ and $y^1=b^1$, but I couldn't complete this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The codomains of the functions you defined is $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @jjagmath oh you’re right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $(f \times g)((1,0),(-1,0)) = (0,0) = (f \times g)((2,0),(-1,0))$ but $((1,0),(-1,0)) \ne ((2,0),(-1,0))$ so it's not injective.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry didn’t realize that.